# Problem on analytic function on an open connected domain.

Tags: complex-analysis

U be an open connected subset of C (the complex number field). f: U---> C be an analytic function. which vanishes on a open neighbourhood of a point 'z' in U . What can we say about the function f and the set of such 'z' points. Is the set open or closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Identity theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) gives that $f$ vanishes on $U$.

It also implies that the zero points of an analytic function are isolated.

Comment: But if f is a non constant analytic function , then I think that the set I mentioned in the question is empty. Is it true?

Comment: What set? Can you write it explicitly?

Comment: A={z in U : f vanishes on a open neighbourhood of z in U} ,B={ z in U : f(z)=0}. I think A is the empty set. And B has no limit point and empty interior.( if f is non constant)

Comment: Yes, that's right. And both statements follow from the mentioned theorem.

Comment: Yes, Thank you @RodrigoDias